# Is there a route that would allow travel to the US from the UK or Schengen area, given the US travel ban?

Tags: usa, covid-19

I'm a European citizen living in the US on a work visa. Due to some unfortunate circumstances, I need to urgently visit my home country. However I would like to get back to the US after my visit is complete. Flying from the US to Europe is not a problem as there are still daily flights between some city pairs. However going back could be tricky, as [the US bans](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/) anyone who has been in the Schengen area in the past 14 days from re-entering the country.

Is there a flight route that would let me from Europe to some country, stay there for 14 days and then fly to the US? Canada is out, as they've banned international visitors. Mexico seems to keep their border open, but I [don't see](https://www.mexico-airport.com/departures.php?day=tomorrow) any direct European flights from their airports. Almost every other country either suspended flights or doesn't allow foreign nationals to enter.

Comment: There had been extensive discussion for Chinese students/workers trying to go back to China (and a few who wants to go back to U.S.), the conclusion is currently Mexico City is the only feasible (albeit tedious and expensive) option to return to US (transit via ICN or NRT). But European passports have additional privileges in some other countries so maybe there are better options.

Comment: Additionally, the discussions I read also indicated DXB is resuming services. Apparently Air China has now scheduled flights from Beijing to Dubai on May 7 (of course, things can change), which may allow more transit options via Emirates and other airlines.

Comment: @zhantongz transit alone wouldn't help, unfortunately you'll need to wait out for 14 days somewhere before returning from Europe.

Comment: You may have more options for going to other countries, though, if the hub restarts service.

Comment: Oh I actually forgot the obvious, Canada allows transit if the connecting airport has appropriate facility (e.g. international transit zone).

Comment: Have you looked to see if you, as a US resident, qualify as an exception to that 14 day rule?

Comment: Maybe take the [direct Paris - Saint Pierre et Miquelon](http://airsaintpierre.com/en/) flight, this is domestic after all :-).  But then again, then you're still in the EU so it won't allow you to go anywhere...

Comment: @MarkJohnson according to the [official regulation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/), no exceptions exist for work visa holders.

Comment: @gerrit Actually, Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon is not in the EU. Rules regarding travels to overseas territories of France are different than those which apply to mainland France and entry is likely to be denied. Not sure how a stay in Saint-Pierre would be handled on the US end.

Comment: @Relaxed In TIMATIC, "France" includes SPM (**not** other DOM-TOM), so boarding would be allowed, plus there's no SPM border control for arrivals from CDG

Comment: @Crazydre Boarding would be allowed where and by who? Police checks typically take place before departure and I don't think the French police relies on TIMATIC. Either way, SPM is not in the EU or the Schengen area. That's important because there are [separate restrictions](http://outre-mer.gouv.fr/covid-19-liaison-aerienne-des-territoires-ultramarins-communique-de-presse) and only the form for travel to mainland France [includes exceptions for EU citizens and residents](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage).

Comment: Now currently in France even domestic travel is restricted, I didn't mean to suggest the Saint Pierre et Miiquelon route seriously.  It just seemed a creative idea.  No idea how travel between SPM and Canada is at the moment.

Comment: Aeromexico appears to offer once per week flights to both AMS and CDG: https://aeromexico.com/en-us/actions-covid19

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk good find! Care to add an answer?

Comment: There may be other flights to Europe available as well, just operating at a frequency of less than once per day.  (This applies to my "Brazil" answer below as well.)

Comment: @gerrit An acquaintance recently went USA-SPM overland and back, and was told by the PAF in SPM that visits are allowed for "European"+Canadian citizens (she used a Dutch ID card for SPM, and a US green card for US+Canada)

Comment: @Relaxed Per TIMATIC, US allows entry for French citizens residing in SPM, but not to others having visited SPM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are now numerous flight options from the EU to Mexico:

[image]

Vacation spots such as Cancun [have reopened](https://www.traveloffpath.com/cancun-and-playa-del-carmen-have-officially-reopened-for-tourism/) and allow foreigners to stay:

> The tourism hotspots of Cancun and Playa Del Carmen have officially reopened to tourists. Surrounding vacation hotspots like Tulum, Isla Mujeres and Cozumel also reopened today.

Likewise Mexico City [has also reopened](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2020-06-mexico-city-reopening-high-coronavirus.html) if you'd like to stay there instead:

> The capital's historic center is scheduled to reopen Tuesday, followed by restaurants and hotels Wednesday, but with half their normal capacity.

And finally, there are plenty of direct flights from Mexico to the US at the moment:

[image]

Comment: Accepting the answer now that Mexico has partially reopened and expanding it with more detail (hope you don't mind).

Answer (score 8):

Given that Canada allows transit and has flight to Europe and Mexico, you can do Europe-Canada-Mexico-14 days-USA, **assuming no additional restriction is imposed in coming days** (not a safe assumption, so only do this is absolutely urgent and necessary).

The Canadian Embassy in Switzerland suggested to Canadian citizens in Switzerland there are still flights operating from London Heathrow or Frankfurt by Air Canada.

UK has no current restrictions for European passengers transiting. But Germany may deny entry (at land borders, at least). Transiting to home countries is allowed by Germany but I'm not sure if this kind of itinerary will be accepted by the border.

The flights to Toronto (YYZ) offer the possibility of airside transfer **if the terminal is the same and baggage is checked through**. You can check if a pair of flights is compatible at https://www.torontopearson.com/en/connections. Overnight connections may require you to pick up your baggage.

---

> **Transit passengers**
>
> The Orders exempt foreign nationals in transit through Canada to another country. Given the interplay between the interim order under the Aeronautics Act and related emergency orders under the Quarantine Act, the airport of arrival into Canada must have the facilities to permit the foreign national to connect to their destination without the foreign national having to present themselves for examination to enter Canada.
>
> - https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/service-delivery/coronavirus/travel-restrictions.html#transit

---

Canada has a **mandatory mask requirement** for air passengers. You will be refused boarding without appropriate face coverings.

> If you are planning to return to Canada, please note the new Transport
>   Canada’s requirement:
>
> Since 20 April, Transport Canada will require air operators to verify
>   that all travellers have a removable cloth face covering available for
>   use during their trip, even if the travellers are not showing any
>   symptoms.  When travelling by air, you will be asked to cover your
>   mouth and nose where possible, and must do so when a two-metre
>   distance between you and others cannot be observed. At a minimum,
>
> - at airport screening checkpoints, where the screeners cannot always keep two metres of separation from you;
> - when you cannot physically distance from others, or as directed by the airline employees; and
> - when directed to do so by a public health order or Public Health official.
>
> If you do not have one available for your trip, the air operator will
>   be required to deny you entry into the sterile area, or boarding on
>   the aircraft.
>
> It is your responsibility to bring the required cloth face covering to
>   the airport. You will not be provided with one if you do not have one.
>   Consular officials from the government of Canada will not be in a
>   position to provide masks either.
>
> **How to make simple cloth face coverings**
>
> There are many online resources available with information on how to
>   make simple cloth face coverings. The Public Health Agency of Canada’s
>   website
>   (https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/diseases/2019-novel-coronavirus-infection/prevention-risks/instructions-sew-no-sew-cloth-face-covering.html) provides suggestions for simple “do it yourself” cloth
>   covers that can be easily made from inexpensive materials found at
>   home, or even while travelling. In general, though:
>
> choose fabric that can be laundered without damage;
>   -   include multiple layers of fabric;
>   -   allow for breathing without restriction; and
>   -   think about having more than one for each traveller, so it can be replaced if damp or soiled.
>
> Cloth coverings should fit snugly but comfortably against the side of
>   your face, be secured with ties or ear loops and cover your face and
>   nose. It should be easy to put on and take off when necessary (e.g.,
>   identity verification check).
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> Cloth face coverings should not be worn by:
>
> - children under the age of two;
> - anyone who has trouble breathing; or
> - anyone who is unconscious, incapacitated or otherwise unable to remove the mask without assistance.
>
> Also note that you may be asked to remove your face covering for the
>   purpose of identity verification at the boarding gate and the
>   customs-controlled area when you arrive at the Canadian airport or
>   when asked to do so by Canada Border Services Agency officers or
>   public health officials.
>
> You are encouraged to use hand sanitizer before removing and after
>   replacing your face covering.
>
> Check our advice for travellers arriving in Canada at
>   https://www.canada.ca/Coronavirus  (restrictions and exemptions, mandatory
>   face covering and self-isolation).

Frankfurt (Hessen) requires face-nose covering.

> Please note that since April 27, 2020, masks have been required all over Hessen in local public transport vehicles and in the public areas of shops, banks and post offices. This regulation also applies to the bus shuttle and SkyLine, as well as shops at Frankfurt Airport.
>   - https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/news/information-on-the-coronavirus.html