# Are there any restrictions on European citizens entering Mexico during the coronavirus pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, mexico, eu-citizens

As mentioned in a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156988/is-there-a-route-that-would-allow-a-european-citizen-to-travel-from-the-us-and-b?noredirect=1#comment390948_156988), I need to fly from the US to Europe and back due to some urgent unfortunate business. On my way back I will need to stay out of the Schengen area for 14 days before I'm allowed back, due to a [government regulation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/) signed into law back in March.

It looks like Mexico city still has direct flights to both Europe and the US, so it looks like the optimal option on the way back to the US. But are there currently any restrictions whatsoever on flying into Mexico as a foreign national? Can I fly in, rent a hotel room, stay for 14 days, and fly out? Normally I'd check the [IATA travel center](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) for a list of restrictions, but they don't list any.

Update: [looks like Cancun is now open](https://www.traveloffpath.com/cancun-and-playa-del-carmen-have-officially-reopened-for-tourism/)?

Comment: Maybe not, given that President Bolsonaro pretty much thinks Covid is a hoax :-)

Comment: Hotel room would be hard. The Mexican government has mandated a closure of hotels in Mexico City except for essential business.

Comment: @Traveller Bolsonaro is the President of Brazil, not the President of Mexico.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica So he is! Stupid mistake :-)

Comment: @Traveller No worries. You probably just read JonathanReez' other thread which devolved into using Brazil as a possible transit point.

Comment: I am aware that CBP were being very strict (possibly denying entry) to Europeans/non-US travelers coming from Europe trying to enter the US via Mexico **by land**.  I am unsure whether that meant the same for flying into the US via Mexico.  If you are a US citizen/resident then there won't be restrictions entering the US from Mexico.  Unsure on entering Mexico from Europe though

Comment: Furthermore Mexico has recently entered what they call "phase 3" where they are starting to enforce travel for essential purposes only.  There are police and military checkpoints in my area to discourage non-essential travel (although at this point they haven't started arresting people here, but I believe they have in other areas).  This may have an effect on entry into the country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update (2020-09-22): European citizens can still enter Mexico (regardless of the means of transportation) and hotels are progressively reopening. From https://www.afar.com/magazine/can-americans-visit-mexico-right-now ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200917171004/https://www.afar.com/magazine/can-americans-visit-mexico-right-now)) (2020-09-15):

> Mexico’s states have each had different phased reopenings, depending on the number of cases and hospital occupation, among other metrics. On June 1, the government introduced a national “stoplight” system to phase in the return of nonessential activities. Red states are essentially in lockdown, with just essential activities allowed; oranges states allow restaurants, hotels, and stores to open with limited capacity. Daily updates are [posted here](https://coronavirus.gob.mx/).

Answer (score 12):

It does not appear that the Mexican government is presently banning entry by foreign nationals, but [you will not be able to rent a hotel room](https://www.gob.mx/sectur/articulos/actualizacion-del-protocolo-de-atencion-para-personas-en-centros-de-hospedaje-y-restaurantes-durante-la-cuarentena-obligatoria-por-covid-19-240964?idiom=es) unless you are traveling for *actividades económicas esenciales*.

For further information in English, see [the US Embassy in Mexico's COVID-19 information page](https://mx.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/), though note of course that the US Embassy does not officially speak for the Mexican government and everything (including, but certainly not limited to, US entry restrictions if that's your ultimate goal) is subject to change on short notice.

It is better for you and your community if you are able to limit travel during this period. Consider if your urgent business can be done remotely from the US, or if you can stay in Europe after you finish this business.

Comment: Is Airbnb allowed to operate?

Comment: @JonathanReez Airbnb in Mexico has told their hosts they are not able to host currently. Source I live in Mexico and have friends who are airbnb hosts (multiple friends)

Comment: Any updates on this, given https://www.traveloffpath.com/cancun-and-playa-del-carmen-have-officially-reopened-for-tourism/? I've opened a bounty for an up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, based on the [Embassy of Mexico in Germany notice of the 18th of March 2020](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/alemania/index.php/de/), the government of Mexico imposes no restrictions for people entering from Europe or any other country because of the coronavirus.

The site also states the the consulate offices reopened on the 4th of May, so one can assume that this notice is up to date.

The screenshot was taken on the 9th of June 2020.

---

**Note**:
The German (and as far as I can tell from the Spanish) text differs in meaning from the English

- using the word **flights** instead of **peaple entering** (Einreisende)

[image: Embassy of Mexico in Germany, notice of 2020-03-18]

---

**Source**:

- [Embassy of Mexico in Germany](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/alemania/index.php/de/)

Comment: But what about hotels?

Comment: @JonathanReez Well the Embassy won't have information on that, but your source states that Mexico has a regional 'traffic light' system. Orange seem to mean that tourism (thus hotels) are allowed. One would then have to find a source where the regional classification is listed and look up your area of interest. The system seems to be similar to that of France.

Comment: the English translation provided by the Embassy is fine; "viaje" most closely means "journey" or "trip" (a traveler is a "viajera/o") but flights are the only sorts of trips that are really relevant traveling from Europe to Mexico.