# Best route to reach the United States from a Schengen Country

Tags: usa, covid-19, italian-citizens

I need to reach the United States from a Schengen Country (I am an Italian Citizen), but as you may know, President Trump has issued a travel ban preventing to enter the US to those who have been in the Schengen area (plus UK and Ireland) in the last 14 days. Please note that I am already fine with visa and the rest of the documentation that I need to show at the US border.

To comply with the proclamation, I'm looking for the most convenient place to do this. For convenient I mean that:

- the 14-day "quarantine" country admits Italian citizens into its borders;
- there is a reliable airlines that does not stop again in the Schengen area while reaching the US (otherwise I would invalidate the 14 days out).
- if the place is nice or not too expensive (or both) it would be nice as well, but this is secondary compared to the previous two points.

As for now, I identified Istanbul (Turkey) as I heard that Turkish Airlines is good and I see it has a direct flight to Miami. I was also trying to understand if the Dominican Republic admits Italians into its territory (I'm waiting for an answer from the embassy).

Does someone know/has tried other good options?

Comment: Allthough I understand the need for the question, the needed answers to travel from a **low infected** to a **higher infected** area for a 14 day quarantine to be qualified to enter an **even higher infected** area is more of a product of [The Ministry of Silly Walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ministry_of_Silly_Walks) than sound advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a route that would allow travel to the US from the UK or Schengen area, given the US travel ban?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156988/is-there-a-route-that-would-allow-travel-to-the-us-from-the-uk-or-schengen-area)

Comment: Thank you Jacob, that's very useful. And Mark your totally right, but I'm starting to work in a National Lab in the US, that is why I need to reach the country. Fortunately I will be in a low population density area, which has not been hit so hard by the virus.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the list](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html) of countries published by the CDC that are included in the 14-day rule:

> (Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Monaco, San Marino, Vatican City)

There are a few Europe countries not on this list that are close to Italy:

- Croatia
- Bosnia and Herzegovina
- Serbia
- Montenegro
- North Macedonia
- Albania

From the above countries, taking into account both distance from Italy and direct flights to the USA, Serbia was the best.

Entry requirements to Serbia for Italian citizens (obtained [here](http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-regime/81-consular-foreigners-to-serbia/11467-italy-for-cons)):

> [image]

Serbia has lifted their entry restrictions so you can enter there.

To travel to the USA, I found direct flights run by Air Serbia from BEG Belgrade Nikola Tesla -> JFK New York John F. Kennedy.

These direct flights seem to run every other day/every 3 days:

> [image]

Therefore, I recommend:

- Flying to Serbia from Italy
- Spending 14 days in Serbia
- Flying direct to the USA

Comment: I've heard many stories of airlines selling tickets and then cancelling flights, which is not very surprising. However, I can say that I know a few people who have flown on this flight in the last few weeks, so it may be a better bet than some other options.