# Travelling from Europe to US while avoiding the Schengen zone ban

Tags: visas, usa, schengen

I am going to apply soon for a US visa while currently being in the Schengen Zone (Germany). I am not a EU citizen but currently here on a work permit. I want to travel to US to continue my employment in the US. Currently, there is a ban on travel to US from Schengen countries. Assuming that I get my visa soon (it is not under the banned categories), what are the ways for me to fly back to US?

For example, I am thinking to travelling to Croatia or Serbia, staying for 14 days in a quarantine there and then flying to US because I think I can travel to these countries with my National D Visa/Work Permit while these countries are not in the Schengen zone.

What would be your advice? I am also a bit afraid of getting stuck in the e country and not being able to go back to Germany if there are some unknown rules prohibiting me from flying back to US.

Comment: Never mind the Schengen zone ban...  What makes you think it's a good time to visit the US?  I'm a US citizen living in Germany, and I wouldn't go to the US right now.

Comment: I don’t think you can make any decision about possible travel routes unless and until you have your visa. Anything could happen between now and then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a route that would allow travel to the US from the UK or Schengen area, given the US travel ban?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156988/is-there-a-route-that-would-allow-travel-to-the-us-from-the-uk-or-schengen-area)

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk yes, that is a helpful answer.